# Input Mapping Blob Shows Error in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, blob, wso2-data-services-server

What are the steps to upload and save images in db through wso2 dss service?

I need to store image as blob in database , so i created services in **wso2 dss** to insert image , in that,i gave input

mapping of image as **BLOB** for **sqltype** , but it makes the service as faulty service , when i

change the **sqltype** its working . what i have to do for inserting images through **wso2 dss**

service.

Comment: Could you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation[1], you can save images in DSS as a binary data type. Also there is a sample[2] which demonstrates a file upload/download/preview application with the use of several features available in the WSO2 Data Services Server.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Data+Types+of+Mappings#DataTypesofMappings-Binarydatatype

[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/File+App+Service+Sample